# Setting cookies for a website with a CNAME record

Tags: azure, cookies, cname

I've domain ***xyz.com*** which is on **godaddy.com**
I've created a **CNAME** record (***sub.xyz.com***) that points to another website on **Azure**.
So, when I'm setting a cookie, can I use ***sub.xyz.com***? Will it work?

Also, I don't need the cookie to be accessed in ***xyz.com***. That is just a marketing website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can set cookies for *sub.xyz.com* from within a site deployed as *some-long-name.azurewebsites.net* but this will only work for users who open it via *sub.xyz.com* in their browser. If they open it as *some-long-name.azurewebsites.net* then of course setting cookies will be ignored by their browsers.